# Can't Add/ Edit Categories After Upgrading Magento to 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, edit, categories

After upgrading Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.0 we can't add/ edit categories.
When clicking Catalogue/ Manage Categories in the Admin Panel, the categories descriptions are showing for 1/10 of a second and then dissapear. 
The categories descriptions are shown in the frontend, but not in the admin panel.
Also when clicking one of the tabs (manage categories), "#" is beiing added to url.
Does anybody know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Check for javascript errors in Console tab of your browser.

Comment: I'm getting these 2 errors: https://mywebsite/js/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css and https://mywebsite/js/infortis/jquery/jquery-for-admin.min.js --->Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. But when i search for this files, i can't find them. These files also don't exist in the original files.

Comment: Based on these errors you have a conflict between jquery and prototype. Find where jquery is added into your admin panel inside a layout.xml file within: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout and comment it out or open up the template you're calling it in the admin and put noconflict clause.

Comment: have you removed ultimo theme??

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini settings by adding:

```
phpinfo();
die;
```

at the top of your index.php

You likely have your

> memory_limit

set too low, likely at 128m.

Increase this to 256/512/1024/2048 until satisfied.

Comment: I have done this and still can't add/ edit categories in the admin panel. When clicking on "Manage Categories" the category descriptions (under the tabs) are shown briefly and then dissapear. Also nothing happenes when i click those tabs or when i try to add a new (root/sub)category.

Answer (score 0):

i had face same problem on Saturday and then i search in my db and delete this row then i am able to see my categories this problem is not for upgrading magento but it is because of ultimo theme extension

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything. Finally I contacted my hosting company and this is what they found out. (which is weird because I have created many magento themes and never had an issue of this before even with the latest version)  Thank you for contacting support. After looking into this for you I am seeing that there are some mod_security errors getting generated when you click on one of the categories. So we fix this on our end for you.

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and after about a months worth of testing I pinned it down to mod_security.

my hosting allows me to turn this off and after doing so, the categories worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, disabling mod-security and re-enabling afterward fixed this for me